# How to write java regular expression for this txt file

Tags: java, regex

Thanks for your help

I hope to get the **Id** and category for each item in a txt file as follow:

```
Id:   0
ASIN: 0771044445
discontinued product

Id:   1
ASIN: 0827229534
  title: Patterns of Preaching: A Sermon Sampler
  group: Book
  salesrank: 396585
  similar: 5  0804215715  156101074X  0687023955  0687074231  082721619X
  categories: 2
   |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & Spirituality[22]|Christianity[12290]|Clergy[12360]|Preaching[12368]
   |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & Spirituality[22]|Christianity[12290]|Clergy[12360]|Sermons[12370]
  reviews: total: 2  downloaded: 2  avg rating: 5
    2000-7-28  cutomer: A2JW67OY8U6HHK  rating: 5  votes:  10  helpful:   9
    2003-12-14  cutomer: A2VE83MZF98ITY  rating: 5  votes:   6  helpful:   5

Id:   2
ASIN: 0738700797
  title: Candlemas: Feast of Flames
  group: Book
  salesrank: 168596
  similar: 5  0738700827  1567184960  1567182836  0738700525  0738700940
  categories: 2
   |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & Spirituality[22]|Earth-Based Religions[12472]|Wicca[12484]
......
```

The result should be organized as:

```
1 Book

2 Book

3 Book
```

Then, I write a java program to extract the information:

```
class Main
{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  { 

    String file="/Users/swing/Desktop/test.rtf";  

      BufferedReader br;

      try 
      {
          br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

          String line;      

          String re1=".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
          String re2="";    // ID 1

          String re3="((?:[c-z][a-z]+))";   // Category 1

          Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
          Matcher m = p.matcher(file);

          while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
          {
            m=p.matcher(line);

              if (m.find())
              {
                  String id1=m.group(1);
                  String category1=m.group(2);
                  System.out.print(" "+id1.toString()+" "+" "+category1.toString()+" "+"\n");
              }    
          } 
      }  
      catch (FileNotFoundException e)    
      {         
          e.printStackTrace();  
          System.out.println("fail");}   
      }
}
```

Since I have no experience for using **java** regular expression, so the result is wrong as follow, could you help me rectify the wrong codes ?  Thanks !

Wrong output:

```
\r  tf 

\font  tbl 

color  tbl 

ar  gl 

ardir  natural 

ardir  natural 

AS  IN 

dis  continued 

AS  IN 

tit  le 

gro  up 

ales  rank 

simi  lar 

....
```

Comment: Last day of earth... God will forgive you my son

Comment: @user3045306 What does it mean `category for each item`? Could you provide the correct output for the regex you want according to your example input?

Comment: @Tafari sorry for the inconvenience, category means the group of product, for example, for product ID 1, the category (group) is Book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this regex and the options you alraedy have selected (meaning dotall and case insensitive):

**PATTERN**

```
Id:\s+?(\d).+?(?:group:|discontinued)\s(\w+?)\s
```

**INPUT**

the .txt file you have provided in the question

**OUTPUT**

Matches:

```
1. Group 1: 0
   Group 2: product

2. Group 1: 1
   Group 2: Book

3. Group 1: 2
   Group 2: Book
```

Comment: Thank you, when I change the code to:                                  String Id="\s+?(\d).+?(?:group:|discontinued)\s(\w+?)\s";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Id,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(file);                                                  it still cannot work.... could I change correct ? or has some syntax errors .....

Comment: @user3045306 probably you have to escape same characters, try this: String Id="\\s+?(\\d).+?(?:group:|discontinued)\\s(\\w+?)\\s"; Please accept my answer if it helped you : )

Comment: String file="/Users/swing/Desktop/test.rtf";

Comment: Try to read the whole document and store it as one string, then try to run the matcher using this one string, because when you will use the pattern on each line you will not get any results.

Comment: Trying on the lines ? Sorry for bothering you .If possible, could you show me the codes ?

Comment: No, store all the lines in one string like this (i dont have jave ide here) string all = ""; while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
          {
               all += line;
          } p.matcher(all);

Comment: Still no  output .......    
    String file="/Users/qiuchen/Desktop/test.rtf";  
    String all = "";
    BufferedReader br;
      try 
      {   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
          String line;      
          while((line=br.readLine())!=null) { all += line; }
String Id="\\s+?(\\d).+?(?:group:|discontinued)\\s(\\w+?)\\s";
          Pattern p = Pattern.compile(...);
          Matcher m = p.matcher(all);
 if (m.find())
 {                String id1=m.group(1);
                  String category1=m.group(2);
                  System.out.print(...);
              }     }   ...

Comment: check if the string **all** contains any text, and you should use while(m.find) I guess.

Comment: I have print 'all', it likes:{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1187\cocoasubrtf340 ...

Comment: I add while(m.find()) on the top of if statement , however, the output is still none....

Comment: Make sure that string **all** contains all the data you want to parse from the file, then use the matcher on it. It will give you no output as long as the input is incorrect.

Comment: I found the problem: when program run to "if (m.find())
              {
                  String id1=m.group(1);
                  String category1=m.group(2);
                  System.out.print(" "+id1.toString()+" "+" "+category1.toString()+" "+"\n");
              }"  it will terminate

Comment: @user3045306 and why does it terminate?

Comment: I do not know why it terminate  , everything looks fine, but it  still not work....:(

Comment: @user3045306 there is no error? Nothing? And **ONCE** again do you have all (correct) text from the file in the string **all**?

Comment: I change other Regular Expression, it could have output....  So, I think the reason is that the regular expression cannot match the 'all' string. Then, the value of find is none...

Comment: Paste me the whole and only **all** string and I will tell you if my regex works.

Comment: could give me a email address that I can send you my files？

Comment: @user3045306 It will not help, I'm at work atm and I do not have java IDE here. Well I have better solution use my regex here with the text from that file and you will see if it matches anything [regexr.com](http://regexr.com?37dmv)

Comment: No, I have not figured it out.  Thanks for your patience

Comment: @user3045306 have you tried the link I gave you? As you can clearly see that it works for the text you gave in the question.

Comment: I have seen the link, but I cannot write a regular expression that just obtain number of Id and name of group..

Comment: @user3045306 I gave you the expression which does those things... You can see that it works when you click the link, it will appear there with the text you provided and the correct results.

Comment: Thanks, I have figured it out